# Replacing elements in multidimensional numpy array based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

I am puzzled why this is not working:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,20, 30], [4, 5, 6]])

a[a[:, 0] == 1][:, 2] = [9999, 9999]
```

I expect:

```
a = [[1, 2, 9999], [1, 20, 9999], [4, 5, 6]]
```

But nothing changes. What is wrong?

Comment: AFAIK, `u = a[a[:, 0] == 1]` copies the data because `a[:, 0] == 1` is an advanced index. Next, `u[:, 2]` indexes into that copy, so assignment affects the copy, not the original array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, you're currently updating an in-memory copy, not your original array.

You can use direct indexing:

```
a[a[:,0]==1, 2] = 9999
```

or with `numpy.where` (not necessary here):

```
a[np.where(a[:,0]==1)[0], 2] = 9999
```

updated `a`:

```
array([[   1,    2, 9999],
       [   1,   20, 9999],
       [   4,    5,    6]])
```